# excel convert column to row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to unpivot the excel sheet, I have already tried transpose, unpivot and all, but not succeeded.

This is my first sheet

[image]

and this is my second sheet

[image]

i want to the result like this.

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything on your own? Can you, at least, better explain (in words) which algorithm to be applied in order to obtain "the result"? Should the first sheet keep the sales and the second one Inventory? In the first sheet "Company1", "Company2" exist, but in the second one only "Company"...

Comment: First sheet sales and Second sheet Inventory thats correct.

Comment: Please, try answering the second part of the clarification question. What about "Company" versus "Company1, 2 ..."? Is it only a matter of wrong column fit? How many such companies and rows in each sheet do you estimate?

Comment: not sure about how many companies depend, this report is imported from SAP I guess. let's say 32. 1, 2 that one is company ID not wrong entry.

Comment: Where are the "company ID" in the second pictures? Are there exactly the same records, in terms of Columns A:B and rows 1:2, sorted exactly the same? Do you guess about the sheet provenience? Did you offer to "solve the problem" asking us, since you do not know the provenience and details?

Comment: i guess ur getting angry to me , it is there,ofcouse i copied that data from excel sheet column became small thats the reason you cant see am sorry for that. but its the same header like sheet1. i am here bcoz i dont know how i can solve the problem.

Comment: But, did you try something on your own? You were talking about Transpose, unpivot... Can you show us what you tried? Maybe we will better understand your need looking to the code. And yes, it sound strange to only guess the workbook provenience... Beside all that, can you answer my last question about the similarity between the two involved worksheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in Power Query by doing a NestedJoin of the two tables.

The code assumes that every company with sales of an item also has an inventory for that item.

- I named the tables `Inventory` and `Sales`
- Unpivot both tables
- NestedJoin of `Inventory` with `Sales` table, with the keys being `Product and Attribute`
- Expand the joined table on the `Value` parameter.
- Create the Product Code table by duplicating the Model table
- Rename, Reorder, and sort the columns to get your desired result.
- **Note** I did not add the Store Code column as I don't know how you are determining that from the data.

**M Code** *Except for the lines starting with `Source2 = ..` and  `tbl =`, the steps could be entered from the UI.*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Inventory"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product", type text}, {"Product Desc", type text}, {"Company 1", Int64.Type}, {"Company 2", Int64.Type}, {"Company 3", Int64.Type}, {"Company 4", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Product", "Product Desc"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Sales"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Product", type text}, {"Product Desc", type text}, {"Company 1", Int64.Type}, {"Company 2", Int64.Type}, {"Company 3", Int64.Type}, {"Company 4", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Product", "Product Desc"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

    tbl = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Product","Attribute"},#"Unpivoted Other Columns1",{"Product","Attribute"},"Joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(tbl, "Joined", {"Value"}, {"Value.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Joined",{{"Value", "Inventory"}, {"Value.1", "Sales"}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}, {"Product", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Attribute", "Product", "Product Desc", "Inventory", "Sales"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Attribute", "Store Name"}, {"Product", "Model"}, {"Product Desc", "Product"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"Store Name", "Model", "Product", "Sales", "Inventory"}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Reordered Columns1", "Model", "Model - Copy"),
    #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"Store Name", "Model", "Product", "Model - Copy", "Sales", "Inventory"}),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns2",{{"Model - Copy", "Product Code"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns2"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ron, it works. You are a magician StackOverflow it self deleted the question bcoz of the details but you understand without explanation. amazing. you are really a magician.